# caching streaming-batch join calcs in spark structured streaming

Tags: python, pyspark, streaming, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I'm curious whether there is a way (or if it is optimal) to cache the result of a calculation carried out on a stream-batch join in spark Structured Streaming.

For example, I want to join a stream with a batch dataframe, then do a window calculation on the joined data, then output the result to two sinks (see the image below). If the initial data were two batch dataframes, then I would consider `df.cache()`'ing the result to make sure that the calculation doesn't run twice (once for each sink).

But in the streaming-batch join context, can/should you `cache` the result of the window calculation? Is there an advantage? A disadvantage? Or is there a better way to approach this?
[image: stream-batch join diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing/recomputing to several sinks it can be useful.
To be precise, I got a nice performance improvement when doing this, but in a foreachBatch scenario, where there was multiple complex calculations going on the cached DataFrame, one of which was loading data from HBase, which I wanted to avoid duplicating.
I would also consider caching only the static DataFrame, since it is always present in the joins.